# Unity3d JsonUtility.FromJson() read from TextAsset works in app, fails in Test Runner

Tags: unity-game-engine, tdd, test-runner

The following code works fine in my application (Unity 2019.3.0f6). It reads from Assets/Resources/lesson-text.json and writes the expected logs to the console:

```
// file to read lessons from
public TextAsset jsonFile;

 internal JsonLessonList LoadLessonFromFile()
{
    JsonLessonList testLessonList = JsonUtility.FromJson<JsonLessonList>(jsonFile.text);

    foreach (JsonLesson lesson in testLessonList.jsonLessonList)
    {
        Debug.Log("Found lesson: " + lesson.Name);
    }

    return testLessonList;
}
```

I'm wanting to read the same file when using Unity's Test Runner:

```
    [UnityTest]
    public IEnumerator TestFileParsesOkTest()
    {
        JsonLessonList testLessonList = jsonReader.LoadLessonFromFile();
        Assert.IsNotNull(testLessonList);

        yield return null;
    }
```

but I keep getting this exception:

### TestFileParsesOkTest (0.019s)

### Unhandled log message: '[Exception] NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. Use UnityEngine.TestTools.LogAssert.Expect

JsonReader.LoadLessonFromFile () (at Assets/Scripts/JsonReader.cs:68)

### JsonReader.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/JsonReader.cs:37)

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I know the file format is ok because it works from the app.  I think the problem is that "TextAsset jsonFile" that is set through the unity editor is not being seen by the Test Runner.  How do I make this work?

```
    [Test]
    public void JsonFileResourceTest()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(jsonReader.jsonFile);
    }
```

results in:

### JsonFileResourceTest (0.020s)

Expected: not null
  But was:  null

(The test driven development tag is because I got the very simplest read of a file with one field working, and now I want to back up and write a unit test for it and then write tests before coding going forward.)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    jsonReader = new GameObject().AddComponent<JsonReader>();
    jsonReader.jsonFile = Resources.Load("lesson-test") as TextAsset;
}

// Verify class exists
[Test]
public void JsonReaderClassExists()
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(jsonReader);
    Assert.IsNotNull(jsonReader.jsonFile);
}
```